# What is the parameter argument used for in Alamofire request? I got results without specifying parameters

Tags: swift, networking, alamofire

I used Alamofire to network in Swift, and didn't supplement information for the parameter argument within the request. I got the results back fine. Does anyone know what the parameter argument is for and when I should supplement information for it?

```
    let editedFlowerName = flowerName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20", options: .literal, range: nil)
    let url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&indexpageids"
    guard let wikiURL = URL(string: "\(url)&titles=\(editedFlowerName)") else {fatalError("Error creating url")}
    //print(wikiURL)
    AF.request(wikiURL, method: .get).validate()
      .responseJSON { (response) in
          let json = JSON(value)
          print(json)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters is not mandatory unless you want to send some data along with the request. When using default encoding, the requests `GET`, `DELETE` and `HEAD` encodes the parameters as query string and adds it to the URL. However, for all other requests - `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, `OPTIONS`, `CONNECT` - the parameters are encoded as query string and sent as the body of the request.

You can change this behavior by changing the encoding type.

For example, by setting the encoding to `queryString` you can set or append the encoded query string result to existing query string.

```
URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)
```

Similarly, you can set encoded query string result as the HTTP body of the URL request for all requests using `httpBody`.

```
URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)
```